# How can I better word the phrase 'possibility of reality'?

Tags: word-choice, grammar, synonyms

I'm writing a paper about a sci-fi movie and one of my criteria for the movie being a good movie is the possibility of reality. How can I say the movie has a never ending thrill with the possibility of reality without actually saying possibility of reality?

Comment: Consider "with some likelihood*".

Comment: degree of *realism*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use **[plausibility](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/plausibility)**

"having an appearance of truth or reason; seemingly worthy of approval or acceptance; credible; believable:
a plausible excuse; a plausible plot."